# Python dynamically instantiate QML Components

Tags: python, qml, pyside, pyside6

I want to use Python to dynamically add custom components onto my view.qml, but I am not sure about my method because I can't see the Button.qml component in the resulting window. Ideally, I hope to be able to instantiate several rows of buttons into the ColumnLayout. By the way, Button.qml custom quick example/demo button whose's source code I have included too below. It is not QtQuick Button.qml from the PySide6 library

I thought I could just call functions from the view.qml but apparently not? I have seen another method that involves using a separate Javascript file, but I would like to avoid doing that if possible.

Main.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import  QUrl, QObject
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQuick import QQuickView

class CreateWidgets(QObject):
    
    def instantiate_widgets(self, root, widgetsNeeded):
        #for i in widgetsNeeded:
            root.doSomething
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView);

    qml_file = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'view.qml')
    view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_file))
    if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
        sys.exit(-1)
    
    root = view.rootObject()
    widgetCreator = CreateWidgets()
    widgetCreator.instantiate_widgets(root, 6)
    
    view.show()
    res = app.exec()
    # Deleting the view before it goes out of scope is required to make sure all child QML instances
    # are destroyed in the correct order.
    del view
    sys.exit(res)
```

view.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item{
    function doSomething(){
        var component = Qt.createComponent("Button.qml");
        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            var button = component.createObject(colLayout);
            button.color = "red";
        }
        console.log("Button created");
    }
    ColumnLayout{
        id: colLayout
        Rectangle {
            id: page           
            width: 500; height: 200
            color: "lightgray"  
         }   
    }
}
```

Button.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle { width: 80; height: 50; color: "red"; anchors.fill: parent}
```

(Code reference for questions in comments section)

```
Main.py
import os
import random
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import Property, QUrl, QObject, Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor, QGuiApplication, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide6.QtQuick import QQuickView

ColorRole = Qt.UserRole
BorderRole = Qt.UserRole

class Manager(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model = QStandardItemModel()
        self._model.setItemRoleNames({Qt.DisplayRole: b"display", ColorRole: b"custom", BorderRole: b"custom2"})

    @Property(QObject, constant=True)
    def model(self):
        return self._model

    def add_button(self, text, color, bColor):
        item = QStandardItem(text)
        item.setData(color, ColorRole)
        item.setData(bColor, BorderRole)
        self._model.appendRow(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    manager = Manager()

    view = QQuickView()
    view.rootContext().setContextProperty("manager", manager)
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)

    qml_file = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "view.qml")
    view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_file))
    if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
        sys.exit(-1)

    for i in range(6):
        color = QColor(*random.sample(range(0, 255), 3))
        border = QColor(*random.sample(range(0, 255), 3))
        manager.add_button(f"button-{i}", color, border)

    view.show()
    res = app.exec()
    sys.exit(res)
```

View.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {
    ColumnLayout {
        id: colLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater{
            model: manager.model
            Button{
                color: model.custom
                text: model.display
                border.color: model.custom2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Button.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root

    property alias text: txt.text
    width: 80
    height: 50
    color: "red"
    border.color: "black"

    Text{
        id: txt
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that Python (or C++) provide the information to QML to create the items for example using a model and a Repeater.

On the other hand, if an item is going to be a child of a ColumnLayout then it should not use anchors since there will be conflicts since they both handle the geometry of the item.

Considering the above I have added more elements such as variable text, variable color, etc. to demonstrate the logic.

```py
import os
import random
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PySide6.QtCore import Property, QUrl, QObject, Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QColor, QGuiApplication, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide6.QtQuick import QQuickView

ColorRole = Qt.UserRole


class Manager(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model = QStandardItemModel()
        self._model.setItemRoleNames({Qt.DisplayRole: b"display", ColorRole: b"custom"})

    @Property(QObject, constant=True)
    def model(self):
        return self._model

    def add_button(self, text, color):
        item = QStandardItem(text)
        item.setData(color, ColorRole)
        self._model.appendRow(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    manager = Manager()

    view = QQuickView()
    view.rootContext().setContextProperty("manager", manager)
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)

    qml_file = os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent / "view.qml")
    view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_file))
    if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
        sys.exit(-1)

    for i in range(6):
        color = QColor(*random.sample(range(0, 255), 3))
        manager.add_button(f"button-{i}", color)

    view.show()
    res = app.exec()
    sys.exit(res)
```

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {
    ColumnLayout {
        id: colLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater{
            model: manager.model
            Button{
                color: model.custom
                text: model.display
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root

    property alias text: txt.text
    width: 80
    height: 50
    color: "red"

    Text{
        id: txt
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Update:

Each role must have a different numerical value since otherwise Qt cannot identify it, in your case you could change:

```py
BorderRole = Qt.UserRole + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Just a quick question, in this line `        self._model.setItemRoleNames({Qt.DisplayRole: b"display", ColorRole: b"custom"})
` where are the `display` and `custom` properties coming from? Are these Qt defined?

Comment: @SCP3008 You are creating roles so they can be any value, I use a classic value: "display" and a custom one: "custom"

Comment: @ellyanesc Hi, another question, is it possible for me to use more than role, like more than one UserRole? It seems to not work if I have more than 1, and the documentation seems to imply that you can only use 1 of each type of data role. If there's another custom property in the Button for instance, can I still use model to set that somehow?

Comment: @SCP3008 You can use as many roles as you want, where in the docs does it indicate that you can only use a single role? in the example I use 2 roles: `display` and `custom`

Comment: @ellyanesc I might have been confused by the description for UserRole, but I modified the code you wrote to have another UserRole to set a border color property, and I get the error `Unable to assign [undefined] to QtColor` when I add this new role, which led me to believe that I wasn't allowed to have more than 1 type of role.

Comment: @SCP3008 Check out my update. I do not get used to answering new questions from the OP since otherwise I would never finish answering since there could be thousands of questions. In this case I have taken an exception.

Comment: @ellyanesc Sorry for the inconvenience, but that helps a lot - thank you!